# xsl how to apply-templates correct

Tags: xml, xslt

If we think about html, I want manage 2 div for content data.`1 is list data` and `2 is for summary`. Like this image

[image]

In `xsl`, This is my code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/hotels">
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Transform 2</h2>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>Address</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="hotel[rating >= 4]"/>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="hotel">
<tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>   
    <td><xsl:value-of select="type"/></td>   
    <td><xsl:value-of select="rating"/></td>   
    <td><xsl:value-of select="address"/></td>   
</tr>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And my `XML` code is

```
<hotels>
    <hotel contact="(855) 23 430 732">
        <name>hotel A</name>
        <type>hotel</type>
        <rating>5</rating>
        <address>
            <houseNo>73 </houseNo>
            <street>Preah Monivong Blvd </street>
            <Sangkat>Mean Chey</Sangkat >
            <Khan>Daun Penh</Khan>
            <city>Bangkok</city>
        </address>
        <room>
            <roomType>hotel: standard/deluxe, apartment: studio/2-bedroom/3-bedroom</roomType>
            <price>209</price>
            <description>Descriptions</description>
        </room>
        <room>
            <roomType>hotel: standard/deluxe, apartment: studio/2-bedroom/3-bedroom</roomType>
            <price>210</price>
            <description>Descriptions</description>
        </room>
    </hotel>
    <hotel>
    .....
    </hotel>
```

**My problem:**
 How I can write `second templates` for content summary data. (I stupid to make layout. )

Comment: So what is the problem, processing the sames nodes twice? Use a `mode` on your second template(s) and the `apply-templates`. Or is the problem computing the total and averages? The sample you have shown has data like `<roomType>hotel: standard/deluxe`, I am not sure how code could determine whether a room belongs to either the `standard` or the `deluxe` category, which you seem to want to do in your summary.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a second template for the summary. You could put the required code in the existing template that matches `hotels`. You would make use of `count` and `sum` functions to provide the summary. For example

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Number of Standard Rooms</td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="count(hotel[rating >= 4]/room)"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Average Cost of Standard Rooms</td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(hotel[rating >= 4]/room/price) div count(hotel[rating >= 4]/room)"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

However, it looks like you want to provide separate summaries for "standard" and "deluxe" rooms, although you haven't actually said how to distinguish between them. Assuming there was a way, you could make use of a named template to avoid code repetition:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/hotels">
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Transform 2</h2>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>Address</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="hotel[rating >= 4]"/>
        </table>
        <table>
            <xsl:call-template name="summary">
                <xsl:with-param name="type">Deluxe</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="rooms" select="hotel/room[starts-with(roomType, 'hotel: standard/deluxe,')]" />
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:call-template name="summary">
                <xsl:with-param name="type">Deluxe</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="rooms" select="hotel/room[starts-with(roomType, 'hotel: standard,')]" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="hotel">
<tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>   
    <td><xsl:value-of select="type"/></td>   
    <td><xsl:value-of select="rating"/></td>   
    <td><xsl:value-of select="address"/></td>   
</tr>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="summary">
    <xsl:param name="type" />
    <xsl:param name="rooms" />
    <xsl:if test="$rooms">
        <tr>
            <td>Number of <xsl:value-of select="$type" /> Rooms</td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="count($rooms)"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Average Cost of <xsl:value-of select="$type" /> Rooms</td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="sum($rooms/price) div count($rooms)"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've made a guess as to how to distinguish between standard and deluxe hotel rooms, but it should demonstrate the principle.